# MenuItemButtom action doesn't work

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationitem

I want to add a custom image as left menu item. Thats why I'm using customView else I get my image but in blue.

This is how I achieve it:

```
UIImageView *menuItemImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuButton"]];
UIBarButtonItem *leftMenuItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuItemImageView];
[leftMenuItemButton setAction:@selector(menuClicked:)];
[leftMenuItemButton setTarget:self];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftMenuItemButton;
```

Everything works except when I click my button nothing happens. It never comes in this:

```
- (void)menuClicked:(id)menuClicked {
    NSLog(@"%s menuClicked", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}
```

Someone could help me?

Comment: Use a `UIButton` instead of `UIImageView` and add target to the button. Then use the button as the custom view. Set the image on the button. **OR** use `initWithImage:style:target:action:`. I advise the second option.

Comment: When I use the second option my image is blue and not my original color.

Comment: Use `initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuButton"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to n00bprogrammer:

```
 UIBarButtonItem * menuItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuButton"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(menuClicked:)] ;
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = menuItem;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here seems to be using `ImageView` , UIBarButtonItem target and action only works if the custom view is UIButton.

Try something like this

```
UIButton* someBtn = [UIButton buttonWithType: UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
UIBarButtonItem *leftMenuItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]   initWithCustomView:someBtn];
[leftMenuItemButton setAction:@selector(menuClicked:)];
[leftMenuItemButton setTarget:self];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = leftMenuItemButton;
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Like this I can't set the image.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to create a custom UIButton and UIBarButtonItem

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(menuClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
```

Add the button to navigationBar

```
[self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:barButton, nil]];
```

Comment: This displays nothing :s

Comment: Change imageNamed value of both button states.

Answer (score 0):

Both answers point to the right direction.

This is how I got it working:

```
UIButton *showCalendar = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30)];
showCalendar.frame = CGRectMake( 0, 0, 40, 30 );
[showCalendar setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"calendar"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[showCalendar addTarget:self action:@selector(toggleCalendar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:showCalendar];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, add a tap gesture to your imageview:

```
UIImageView *menuItemImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"MenuButton"]];
UIBarButtonItem *leftMenuItemButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:menuItemImageView];

UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture =
[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                        action:@selector(menuClicked:)];
[menuItemImageView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];
```